# I can't get the source of a Javascript page in Selenium

Tags: javascript, python, selenium

There seems to be several Javascripts and I don't know how to get them.

How can I get the source for this?

At first I was able to get it with requests and BeautifulSoup, but the specification seems to have changed and I had to enable Javascript.

So I started trying with Selenium, but it didn't work.

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.options import Options
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import time


options = Options()
options.add_argument('--user-agent=Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Mac OS X x86_64; rv:57.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/57.0')
driver = webdriver.Chrome('C:\\Users\\PC_User\\Documents\\GitHub\\kutikomi\\bakusai\\chromedriver.exe',options=options)

domain = 'https://bakusai.com'

driver.get('https://bakusai.com/thr_tl/acode=3/ctgid=123/bid=1122/')
soup = BeautifulSoup(driver.page_source, 'html.parser')
threads = soup.find('div', {'id': 'thrListInner'}).find_all('a')


thread_url_list = []

for thread_url in threads:
    urls = thread_url.attrs['href']
    thread_url_list.append(urls)



for thread_url in thread_url_list:
    time.sleep(2)
    thread_urls = domain + thread_url
    thread_res = (driver.get(thread_urls))
    time.sleep(1.5)
    driver.find_element_by_tag_name('body').click()
    driver.find_element_by_tag_name('body').send_keys(Keys.PAGE_DOWN)
    print(driver.page_source)
    time.sleep(1.5)
    # soup_thread = BeautifulSoup(driver.page_source, 'html.parser')
```

Comment: driver.getPageSource() did u tried this ???

Comment: No.I'll try this

Comment: I get getPageSource() is AttributeError.